# Login - How to get a value from database cell into a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to know how can I get from database sql a value from a cell?
Example
table name : login
columns:

```
Name | Birthday
Ina     19

string name = "Select Name from login";
string connection= "connection string path";
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlCommand command = new sqlCommand(name,connect);
string get = command;
```

but I'm sure it's wrong :(

I would like to know how to get the value?

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at tutorial here -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254937%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, there are different ways to get data based on requirement, Do you need single row or multiple rows or single value?

Comment: Only 1 value , there are 2 cells , I want to get from the second

Comment: Why are you updating all of your questions to "test test test ...?"  This makes it so that other people searching for the same solutions can't find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`command.ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
string get = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

You may need to be careful of the possibility of getting a null back from the command too.

Comment: Yep everything worked , what do you mean null back? what do I need to do?

Comment: if your command was `SELECT Name from LoginTable where userID = 123` but no user exists with an ID of 123 then the select will return an empty result set and I think `ExecuteScalar()` will then return a null. This of course means that converting to a string will fail. Which does remind me, you are only getting one piece of data back (the first cell of the first row of the result set) so you should make sure that your query is only expected to return one piece of data. Without a where clause as you have it the results could be undetermined (especially without an order by).

Comment: And feel free to upvote answers that you find useful (ie clicking the up arrow above the score). It makes us happy and gives us even more of a happy feeling than just helping does. :)

Answer (score 1):

you may need to add parameter if there are multiple rows in that table.

```
string nameval = string.empty;
string name = "Select Name from login";
string connection= "connection string path";
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlCommand command = new sqlCommand(name,connect);
using(connect)
{
   var data = command.ExecuteScalar();
   if(data!=null) {nameval = data.ToString();}
}
```